# WebGL selecting internal format

Tags: javascript, html, browser, textures, webgl

What are the valid possible values to pass to `internalformat` in WebGL's `texImage2D` call?  The WebGL spec doesn't seem to make it clear, and I'm not sure which enums from desktop GL documentation will work in WebGL.

WebGL defines: `RGB`, `RGBA`, `RGBA4`, `RGB5_A1`, `RGB565`.  Are all of these guaranteed to be valid internal formats?

Does the `type` parameter get taken in to account?  If I set `internalformat` to `RGB` and `type` to `UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5`, does this guarantee the internal format will be 16-bit?  Or does it always use RGB8 or decide based on other factors?

Comment: `RGBA4`, `RGB5_A1`, `RGB565` are renderbuffer formats not texture formats. See `glRenderbufferStorage` (http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRenderbufferStorage.xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding the following parameters are valid in webgl:

> internalformat: GL_ALPHA, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_RGB, GL_RGBA.
>
> format: GL_ALPHA, GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, GL_LUMINANCE and GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA.
>
> type: GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, and GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1.
>
> internalformat must match format

From the [opengl ES 2.0](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/) documentation:

> internalformat must match format. No conversion between formats is supported during texture image processing. type may be used as a hint to specify how much precision is desired, but a GL implementation may choose to store the texture array at any internal resolution it chooses.

If the webgl documentation does not give enough details maybe the [full](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.24.pdf) opengl es 2.0 documentation can help (chapter 3.7.1). From looking at the [differences between webgl and opengl es 2.0](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/#webgl_gl_differences) there shouldn't be any difference in`glTexImage2D` between webgl and opengl es 2.0